# Why the new data are not saved in the nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

In ActiveAdmin I have an entity editing form with triple nesting. Now I can edit the data that is present in the database. They are saved.

But if I try to add new data, then I get a ROLLBACK error:

```
{:"blocks.texts.block"=>["must exist", "can't be blank"]}
```

*I'll clarify again - existing data in this field is successfully updating.*

But when creating a new entity in this nested form, some kind of problem arises. I tried to track by logs what is sent in the form, what comes before validation and what remains after validation.

Everything comes to form:

```
"blocks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"texts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"value"=>"first value", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"671518"}}, "label_ids"=>["", "54"], "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"18655"}, "1"=>{"texts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"value"=>"tteesstt"}}}}

# => "1"=>{"texts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"value"=>"tteesstt"}}}
```

But before and after validation, this data is no longer available. In `texts` are present only data previously existed.

In ActiveAdmin have this code:

```rb
permit_params :title, :description, :published,
              blocks_attributes: [
                :id, :_destroy,
                texts_attributes: %i[id value _destroy],
                label_ids: []
              ],
              category_ids: []

# ...

f.has_many :blocks, allow_destroy: true do |b_f|
  b_f.inputs do
    b_f.has_many :texts, allow_destroy: true do |b_t_f|
      b_t_f.inputs do
        b_t_f.input :value
      end
    end

    b_f.input :labels, as: :check_boxes, collection: Label.options_for_select, input_html: { multiple: true }
  end
end
```

The initial Post model has this code:

```rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks,
                              allow_destroy: true
```

In Block model:

```rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :texts,
                              allow_destroy: true
```

---

Please tell me why the existing data is updated, and the new ones disappear when saved?

---

**Addition 1**

As I understand it, this is connected not with `texts`, but with `block` - `blocks.texts.block`. But why does the `text` refer to a `block`? Why is the `block` not identifiable? It has the following name in the form: `post[blocks_attributes][1][texts_attributes][0][value]`.

**Addition 2**

If in ActiveAdmin I first add (save to DB) only `block` (second block), and after I add text to this `block`, all two times the save to DB will successfully. That is, the problem is due to the lack of a `block` ID when creating `text` in a single scenario.

It turns out that this is a bug? When adding (using JS) a new HTML form code, must also add the `block_id` for `text`. But now this is not. Now only the existing block in the database has this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple - need to use `inverse_of`. [Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model).

And everything will start to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that some time ago I had a similar issue with associations. Here, form error it looks like texts have no block_id. That's true because you're already saving it. Try that: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html